# Multiple gradients and colors in JavaFX CSS

Tags: css, javafx, colors, radial-gradients

I am trying to have an Ellipse filled with multiple radial gradients and a black background in JavaFX.

I found that it is possible to layer gradients and colors in CSS by separating them with commas. I cannot reproduce it in JavaFX CSS.

CSS working code: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G6A2CYDNR601

JavaFX non working code:

```
Ellipse ellipse = new Ellipse(50,50);
ellipse.setStyle("-fx-fill: radial-gradient(center 100% 50%, radius 100%, blue, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 50%), black;");
```

This code only fills the ellipse with the first gradient (from blue to transparent), and the black background is not shown.

Comment: [mcve] please....

Comment: Take a look at the [JavaFX CSS Reference Guide](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html). The `-fx-fill` CSS property (inherited from `Shape`) only accepts a single `<paint>` value. A `Region`, on the other hand, has the `-fx-background-color` CSS property which accepts a value of `<paint> [, <paint>]*`. So if you want multiple fills you need to use a `Region`. Anyway, what's wrong with using `-fx-fill: radial-gradient(center 100% 50%, radius 100%, blue, black 50%);` on your `Ellipse`?